# Conformality of $z^n$

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

For $n\gt 1$, the function $z^n$ multiplies angles at the origin by $n$, so it is not conformal at $z=0$. The following theorem shows that $z^n$ is conformal at any other point $z$ other than $0$.

**Theorem.** If $f(z)$ is analytic at $z_0$ and $f'(z_0)\neq0$, then $f(z)$ is conformal at $z_0$.

---

Why $z^n$ is not conformal at the origin? I agree with the theorem that $f'(z_0)\neq0$, but I would like to see a "geometric" intuition why this is not true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is.  "Conformal" means preserving the angles.  The mapping $z \mapsto z^{n}$ changes the angles at the origin.

Comment: You mean that $z^n=r^n(cos(n\theta)+i sin(n\theta))$, and then the angle is changed, but then why $z^n$ is conformal at any other $z\neq 0$?

Comment: You can compute an example.  I.e., take a $z \neq 0$ and two directions $v_1, v_2$ emanating from $z$, and note that the angle between the two is related to  $\overline{v_{1}} v_{2}$.  Now compute the 1st-order Taylor terms of $f_{1}(t) = (z + t v_{1})^{n}, \; f_{2}(t) = (z + t v_{2})^{n}$ at $t=0$, and measure the angle between them.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the ray $\gamma_t = \{ re^{it} \mid r \ge 0 \}$ is mapped to $\gamma_{nt} = \{ re^{nit} \mid r \ge 0 \}$, by $f(z) = z^n$.

In particular, the angle between $\gamma_0$ and $\gamma_t$ is multiplied by $n$ under the mapping $f(z) = z^n$, so it is not conformal at $z=0$.